# MVVM light - navigation service android

Tags: c#, android, mvvm-light

Every time when I want to navigate to an activity an exception occures: The inner exception says: No CurrentActivity found...

But I registered the activities with navigation service configure method...
In windows phone project all works fine but not in the android version.

When I start the activity without the navigation service all works fine too...
What went wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ups, I figured it out... I have to use the ActivityBase as Base class (from the mvvm-light lib) for the activities and not the default Activity class...